# Why is ax.patch not listed under the output of plt.getp(ax)?

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()  
plt.getp(ax)
```

Why is `ax.patch` not listed under the output of `plt.getp(ax)`?

Comment: `subplot` should be `subplots` for one thing

Comment: corrected it, thanks

Answer (score 2):

`plt.getp(artist)` returns a list of the gettable and settable properties of an artist.
In the [source code](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/e73dfe1cd6b916c7fdadc4c2c1f996cc7c8a2bb4/lib/matplotlib/artist.py#L1400),

```
getters = [name for name in dir(o)
                   if name.startswith('get_') and callable(getattr(o, name))]
```

There is no `Axes.get_patch()` method. Hence `patch` is not part of the properties that are returned by that function.

I don't think people would oppose a pull request to the matplotlib code making `patch` a gettable/settable property.